# Knockout js: Load model from JSON

Tags: json, knockout.js, mapping, selectlist

I have a problem with my model. I try to load the model from JSON, but it doesn't work good :(
I've created cascading select lists. When I try to save the model to JSON and after that to load it from saved JSON it causes wrong values of select lists.

Here's my binding:

```
<div id="condition-template" type="text/html">
  <div class="condition">
    <select class="textbox1" 
            data-bind="options: entarea, 
                       optionsText : &apos;displayName&apos;,
                       value: selectedArea " ></select>
    <select class="textbox1" 
            data-bind="options: Selectedfields, 
                       optionsText : &apos;fieldDisplayName&apos;,
                       value: selectedField "></select>
    <select class="textbox1" 
            data-bind="options: Selectedcomparisons, 
                       optionsText : &apos;comparsionDisplayName&apos;,
                       value: selectedComparison "></select>    
    <input class="textbox1" type="text" data-bind="value: value"></input>
    <button data-bind='click: save'>Save to JSON</button>
    <button data-bind='click: loadModel'>AddModel</button>
</p>

    <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' > </textarea>
    <inner type = "textarea" id="t_test"></inner>
  </div>
</div>
```

My model is:

```
function Condition() {
 var self = this;
 var sqlArea = function(sqlAreaId, displayName) {
     this.displayName = ko.observable(displayName);
     this.sqlAreaId = ko.observable(sqlAreaId);
 };
 var field = function(fieldId, fieldDisplayName, sqlAreaId, fieldType) {
     this.fieldId = ko.observable(fieldId);
     this.fieldDisplayName = ko.observable(fieldDisplayName);
     this.sqlAreaId = ko.observable(sqlAreaId);
     this.fieldType = ko.observable(fieldType);
 };
 var comparison = function(comparsionId, comparsionDisplayName, fieldType) {
     this.comparsionId = ko.observable(comparsionId);
     this.comparsionDisplayName = ko.observable(comparsionDisplayName);
     this.fieldType = ko.observable(fieldType);
 };
 self.templateName = "condition-template";
 self.entarea = ko.observableArray([new sqlArea(1, "Client"), 
                                    new sqlArea(2, "Order")]);
 self.selectedArea = ko.observable();
 self.fields = ko.observableArray([new field( 1, "Name", 1, 1), 
                                   new field( 2, "Address", 1, 1), 
                                   new field( 3, "Phone number", 1, 1), 
                                   new field( 4, "Manager", 1, 1), 
                                   new field( 5, "Type", 1, 2), 
                                   new field( 6, "Order number", 2, 2), 
                                   new field( 7, "Sum", 2, 2), 
                                   new field( 8, "Date", 2, 3)]); 
 self.selectedField = ko.observable();
 self.comparisons = ko.observableArray([new comparison( 1,">=", 2),
                                     new comparison( 2,">", 2),
                                    new comparison( 3,"<=", 3), 
                                    new comparison( 4,"IN from date", 3),
                                    new comparison( 5,"IN from string", 1)
                                  ]);
 self.selectedComparison = ko.observable();
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //Cascading select list
 self.Selectedfields = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
   var area = self.selectedArea(), sqlAreaId;
   if (area) {
      sqlAreaId = area.sqlAreaId();
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.fields(), function(field) {
          return field.sqlAreaId() === sqlAreaId;
      });
   }
   return [];
 }, self);

 self.Selectedcomparisons = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
     var field = self.selectedField(), fieldType;
     if (field) {
       fieldType = field.fieldType();
       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.comparisons(),function(comparison) {
           return comparison.fieldType() === fieldType;
       });
     }
     return [];
 }, self);
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 self.value = ko.observable(0);

 self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify( ko.mapping.toJS(self), null, 2));
    var test = document.getElementById('t_test');
    test.innerHTML = (JSON.stringify( ko.mapping.toJS(self), null, 2));
 };
 self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");    
 self.loadModel = function() {
    var test = document.getElementById('t_test');
    var data = JSON.parse(test.innerHTML);

     ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
     /* var viewModel = {};
        viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
                    self.updateFromModel(self, viewModel.model);*/
 };
}
ko.applyBindings(new Condition());
```

**UPDATE1:**
http://jsfiddle.net/3EWVR/2/

For example, when i select order/sum/>=/8 and save it to JSON then I choose other values (e.g. client/address/in from string/0) and load saved data models from JSON, I expect to get the original input (order/sum/>=/8) but there is no any values in select item and it dublicates values in the select list.

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample please

Comment: Could you clarify "doesn't work"?  Does it give errors?  Where is the error occurring?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3EWVR/2/

Comment: For example, when i select order/sum/>=/8 and save it to JSON then I choose other values (e.g. client/address/in from string/0) and load saved data models from JSON, I expect to get the original input (order/sum/>=/8) but there is no any values in select item and it dublicates values in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the root of the issue is due to some object reference sharing. Take for consideration the different scenarios depicted in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/vVQv9/).

- However, that basic explanation requires further clarification since `Order` models will cause duplication within the first `<select>` while `Client` models do not. Both types will also cause duplication within the second `<select>`.
- The affected index is always [0] which explains why `Client` doesn't duplicate. *Affected index of `0` part I haven't quite figured out yet*.

For reasons that I have yet to investigate, specifying an `update callback`

```
  ko.mapping.fromJS( init, {
      'selectedArea': {
          update: function (options) {
              return options.data;
          }
      }
  }, new Condition())
```

within the ko.mapping `options` parameters seems to mitigate the problem.

---

An alternative would be to introduce the `optionsValue` binding and lookup the objects when needed via [a ko.utils function](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

---

### Edit

After taking a closer look at the application of `options` into the actual source vs my scaled down example, I still had some object reference issues. So I have [applied my alternative approach](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/R5YCj/).

The `<select>` elements now use the `optionsValue` binding parameter. The only place this affects the source is in `Selectedcomparisons`. You must lookup up the field for access to the `fieldType` property.

```
var selectedField = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Selectedfields(), function (field) {
    return field.fieldId() === self.selectedField();
});
```

---

### Other considerations

- You were parsing the `JSON` and then `ko.mapping.fromJS` on it, I changed that

  `ko.mapping.fromJSON(self.lastSavedJson(), options, self)`
- The `dependentObservables` cannot be written to as defined, so I've flagged them as ignored

  `var options = {ignore: []}
    var propertyNames = Object.keys(self);
    for(index in propertyNames){
      var property = propertyNames[index]
      if(ko.isComputed(self[property])){
         options.ignore.push(property)
      } 
    };`

Comment: I try to add options in my example, but it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/3EWVR/8/ . Can you explain how apply the ko.mapping options parameters for my example?